# using express node.js, call a function in a function and exports and require in router and hand in to ejs when rendering in router

Tags: node.js, module, export, require

can a function be recognized inside a function when both would be exported?
this is my code

```
exports.generateUrlWithParam = function(idpUrl,subUrl,param){
  var url = generateUrl(idpUrl, subUrl);

  if(url == null) {
      return null;
  }

  var paramStr = generateParam(param);

  return url + "?" + paramStr;
}
```

and this function is to be used inside generateUrlWithParam

```
exports.generateUrl = function(idpUrl, subUrl) {
    if((idpUrl == null || ""==idpUrl.trim()) && (subUrl == null || ""==subUrl.trim())) {
        return null;
    }

    let url = idpUrl
    if(!idpUrl.endsWith("/")) {
        url += "/";
    }

    url += subUrl;

    url = url.replace(/\/+/g, "/");

    if(url.startsWith("http:/") && !url.startsWith("http://")) {
        url = url.replace(/^http:\//, "http://");
    } else if(url.startsWith("https:/") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        url = url.replace(/^https:\//, "https://");
    }

    return url;
}
```

and they will be used in ejs file. 
apparently generateUrl is not recognized

i'm using this js file by 'require' in my router file and hand to the ejs file
any ideas would be appreciated in advance thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this function as `var url = exports.generateUrl(idpUrl, subUrl);`